# Create a global variable list/set in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @Companies_List char(25)
SET @Companies_List = ('Amazon','Google','Facebook')

select * 
from companies
where name in @Companies_List
```

I'm new to SQL Server. I'm trying to create a global set containing the values that I want to use in the SQL `where` clause, but apparently the above script wouldn't work. Any idea how I should do it? Many thanks!

Comment: The table variable answer is a good idea.  The table definition matches the variable you declared as `char(25)`.  I would recommend using `varchar(25)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

I would create a `TABLE` variable and do a `JOIN` to it for a list like this:

```
DECLARE @Companies_List TABLE 
(
    Name Char(25)
)

INSERT  @Companies_List (Name)
VALUES  ('Amazon'), ('Google'), ('Facebook')

SELECT  C.*
FROM    Companies       C
JOIN    @Companies_List CL  ON  C.Name = CL.Name
```

If you want something more concrete, you should make a physical `TABLE`.